# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost

Tags: java

This is my server creation code -

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ServerCreation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( 1234 ); 
        System.out.println( "Server created, waiting for client"); 
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println(" Client has connected");

    }
}
```

This is my client code -

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ServerClient {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
    try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find Host");
    }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my client code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException:  localhost
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:223)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:373)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:187)
at ServerClient.main(ServerClient.java:6)
```

I tried to ping my localhost and it's working fine. Not sure what's happening. Please help.

Comment: This code alone can't produce that output, you are catching that exception. Is there more code somewhere?

Comment: isn't there an excessive space? `" localhost"` instead of `"localhost"`

Comment: Is your server code running when you run client code? You need to run server code before client code

Comment: The client code shows you connecting to "local", but the stack trace says " localhost", with an uncaught exception that your code catches.  Please attach the real code for this error.

Comment: It's true that the output is not consistent with what you posted. Besides, shouldn't the address be "localhost" instead of "local"?

Comment: @Messa Socket can also be created by passing String host and int port value (see 7th constructor definition)

Comment: I did try both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" but got the same error. Also, this is the real code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `local` as the host name, you need to have it in your DNS or you hosts files. The right syntax is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or your ip.

Answer (score 0):

better use IP address of the network.
for local host, use 
Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1234);